# Is defining structure inside a function a good way to conceal the structure from other functions?

Tags: function, rust, structure

You can define a structure inside a function like this:

```
fn user_status() -> bool {
    struct UserStatus {
        logined: bool,
        name: Option<String>,
    }
    // ...
    true
}
```

Is this a good way to conceal structure from other functions and is structure defined every time something calls the function or it is created just once?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think this is a perfectly reasonable way to define a type only used within a function.

Types are defined at compile time; there's no "defining" going on at runtime when functions are called.